# Using setter method in AsyncTask onPostExecute

Tags: java, android, android-asynctask

My `onPostExecute` method needs to return a result back to `onCreate()` so it can do stuff with it but I'm struggling to get there.

```
public class ScheduleList extends Activity {

    public String url = "http://www.bbc.co.uk/bbcnews/programmes/schedules/today.json";

    private DownloadJSON mTask = null;


    public static String fetchedJSON = "";
    public static String getFetchedJSON() {
       return fetchedJSON;
    }
  public static void setFetchedJSON(String fetchedJSON) {
     ScheduleList.fetchedJSON = fetchedJSON;
  }


@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_schedule_list);

    // Show the Up button in the action bar.
    setupActionBar();

    TextView tvNotice = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.schedulePreamble);
    tvNotice.setText("Well, hello there...");

    System.out.println("Hello");
    downloadPage();
    System.out.println(getFetchedJSON());

}


public class DownloadJSON extends AsyncTask<String, Integer, String> {
    @Override
    protected void onPreExecute() {
        super.onPreExecute();
    }

    @Override
    protected void onProgressUpdate(Integer... values) {
        super.onProgressUpdate(values);

    }

    @Override
    protected String doInBackground(String... urls) {
        String response = "";
        for (String url : urls) {
            DefaultHttpClient client = new DefaultHttpClient();
            HttpGet httpGet = new HttpGet(url);
            try {
                HttpResponse execute = client.execute(httpGet);
                InputStream content = execute.getEntity().getContent();

                BufferedReader buffer = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(
                        content));
                String s = "";
                while ((s = buffer.readLine()) != null) {
                    response += s;
                }

            } catch (Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
        return response;
    }

    @Override
    public void onPostExecute(String result) {
        setFetchedJSON(result);
    }


}

private void downloadPage() {
    if (mTask != null && mTask.getStatus() != DownloadJSON.Status.FINISHED) {
        mTask.cancel(true);
    }
    mTask = (DownloadJSON) new DownloadJSON().execute(new String[] { url });
}

}
```

Every time I run the code, `System.out.println(getFetchedJSON());` returns nothing which means my `onPostExecute` hasn't actually changed the contents of any variable at all, has it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have modified my code.This code will get your JSON from Url and convert it into a String and a Json Objecct
This will work now

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {
InputStream is = null;
JSONObject jObj = null;
String json = "";
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    Button b = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button1);

    b.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {

            // Making HTTP request
            try {
                StrictMode.ThreadPolicy policy = new StrictMode.ThreadPolicy.Builder().permitAll().build();

                StrictMode.setThreadPolicy(policy); 
                // defaultHttpClient
                String url = "http://api.androidhive.info/contacts/";
                DefaultHttpClient httpClient = new DefaultHttpClient();
                HttpPost httpPost = new HttpPost(url);

                HttpResponse httpResponse = httpClient.execute(httpPost);
                HttpEntity httpEntity = httpResponse.getEntity();
                is = httpEntity.getContent();           

            } catch (UnsupportedEncodingException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            } catch (ClientProtocolException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }

            try {
                BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(
                        is, "iso-8859-1"), 8);
                StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
                String line = null;
                while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
                    sb.append(line + "\n");
                }
                is.close();
                json = sb.toString();
            } catch (Exception e) {
                Log.e("Buffer Error", "Error converting result " + e.toString());
            }

            // try parse the string to a JSON object
            try {
                jObj = new JSONObject(json);
            } catch (JSONException e) {
                Log.e("JSON Parser", "Error parsing data " + e.toString());
            }

            // return JSON String

        }
    });
}

@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
    return true;
}

}
```

Add this line in Android Manifest :-

```
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
```

Comment: I tried running your code but I replaced the `return null` with `System.out.println("Error");`. When I run your code, logcat returns "Error" twice.

Comment: So your are getting a JSONException. Have you checked your url? Because this code is working just fine for me

Comment: @chivano - I have modified my code. It will work now. It was showing NetworkOnMainThreadException error. I have fixed this. Please check it out

Comment: It works, many thanks! Out of interest, am I able to replace `iso-8859-1` with `utf-8`?

Comment: @chivano - Yes you can do that.

Answer (score 0):

The method `downloadPage()` launch your task. This task is executed in other thread and immediately after you launch your task you want to print the result but the task is not over yet. Try this code :

> public class ScheduleList extends Activity {
>
> ```
> public String url = "http://www.bbc.co.uk/bbcnews/programmes/schedules/today.json";
>
> private DownloadJSON mTask = null;
>
>
> public static String fetchedJSON = "";
> public static String getFetchedJSON() {
>     return fetchedJSON;
> }
> public static void setFetchedJSON(String fetchedJSON) {
>     ScheduleList.fetchedJSON = fetchedJSON;
> }
>
>
> @Override
> protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
>
>     super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
>     setContentView(R.layout.activity_schedule_list);
>
>     // Show the Up button in the action bar.
>     setupActionBar();
>
>     TextView tvNotice = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.schedulePreamble);
>     tvNotice.setText("Well, hello there...");
>
>     System.out.println("Hello");
>     downloadPage();
>
> }
>
> public void printFetchedJSON() {
>     System.out.println(getFetchedJSON());
> }
>
>
> public class DownloadJSON extends AsyncTask<String, Integer, String> {
>     @Override
>     protected void onPreExecute() {
>         super.onPreExecute();
>     }
>
>     @Override
>     protected void onProgressUpdate(Integer... values) {
>         super.onProgressUpdate(values);
>
>     }
>
>     @Override
>     protected String doInBackground(String... urls) {
>         String response = "";
>         for (String url : urls) {
>             DefaultHttpClient client = new DefaultHttpClient();
>             HttpGet httpGet = new HttpGet(url);
>             try {
>                 HttpResponse execute = client.execute(httpGet);
>                 InputStream content = execute.getEntity().getContent();
>
>                 BufferedReader buffer = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(
>                         content));
>                 String s = "";
>                 while ((s = buffer.readLine()) != null) {
>                     response += s;
>                 }
>
>             } catch (Exception e) {
>                 e.printStackTrace();
>             }
>         }
>         return response;
>     }
>
>     @Override
>     public void onPostExecute(String result) {
>         setFetchedJSON(result);
>         printFetchedJSON();
>     }
>
>
> }
>
> private void downloadPage() {
>     if (mTask != null && mTask.getStatus() != DownloadJSON.Status.FINISHED) {
>         mTask.cancel(true);
>     }
>     mTask = (DownloadJSON) new DownloadJSON().execute(new String[] { url });
> }
> ```
>
> }

Comment: That code does indeed output the JSON into my logcat panel. Based on that, is there a way for me to access `getFetchedJSON()` within the `onCreate` method? If I try to set the text of a TextView to `getFetchedJSON()`, the TextView becomes blank rather than displaying a long JSON string (as it does in the logcat console of Eclipse).

Comment: replace printFetchedJSON() method by this code : `public void printFetchedJSON() {
    System.out.println(getFetchedJSON());
    TextView tvNotice = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.schedulePreamble);
    tvNotice.setText(getFetchedJSON());
}`